# how to count properly javascript, and show a div if/else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to count two variables, and if one is bigger than number 1 show a div, else don't show anything.

I got a column with 10 inputs, so i wanna check all inputs for the magic word, then count. I just need to show div if x it at least 1 time in one of the inputs.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
var x = 0;
var l = 0;
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  $(document).on("keyup change", ".check" + i, function() {
    if ($(this).val().match(/magicword/i)) {
      l++;
    } else {
      x++;
    }
  });
}

if (x >= 1) {
  $(".nda").show();
}
```

is it better to use show() or toggle()? I want if user deletes magicword div to hide again.

Comment: if you're using jquery, which is a rather different API from plain JS, remember to use the jquery tag. That said, also note that modern JS no longer uses `var`: use `let` for variables you're going to reassign, and use `const` for fixed values. And of course, [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) exist, don't use `+` with strings, template values into strings instead.  (e.g. ```on("...", `.check${i}`, ......```)

Comment: Use `$(".nda").toggle(x >= 1)`. That will hide or show it depending on the value of the condition.

Comment: You're checking `x` when the page is first loaded, not when the user edits one of the inputs.